# Al Zimmermann's Son of Darts

Tags: algorithm, azspcs

There's about 2 months left in [Al Zimmermann's Son of Darts programming contest](http://www.azspcs.net/Contest/SonOfDarts), and I'd like to improve my standing (currently in the 60s) to something more respectable. I'd like to get some ideas from the great community of stackoverflow on how best to approach this problem.

The contest problem is known as the [Global Postage Stamp Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postage_stamp_problem) in literatures. I don't have much experience with optimization algorithms (I know of hillclimbing and simulated annealing in concept only from college), and in fact the program that I have right now is basically sheer brute force, which of course isn't feasible for the larger search spaces.

Here are some papers on the subject:

- [A Postage Stamp Problem (Alter & Barnett, 1980)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2321610)
- [Algorithms for Computing the h-Range of the Postage Stamp Problem (Mossige, 1981)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2007661)
- [A Postage Stamp Problem (Lunnon, 1986)](http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/cgi/content/abstract/12/4/377)
- [Two New Techniques for Computing Extremal h-bases Ak (Challis, 1992)](http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/cgi/content/abstract/36/2/117)

Any hints and suggestions are welcome. Also, feel free to direct me to the proper site if stackoverflow isn't it.

Comment: I don't see a specific question here - needs to be CW ?

Comment: The question is: what algorithms should I use to be #1. If that's too hard, then just Top 25 is fine.

Comment: Cool, it's the Chicken McNuggets problem! (largest number of McNuggets that cannot be purchased, given that McNuggets were sold in batches of 6, 9, and 20)

Comment: @Jason S: No, it's not, actually. In local postage stamp problem, we want to find the _smallest_ sum that can not be achieved; in global postage stamp problem, we want this sum to be maximized. And unlike McNuggets, you can't buy as many as you want, i.e. the envelope can only fit so many stamps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the problem. But maybe you could do things like branch & bound to get rid of the brute force aspect.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound