# Find a repeated numbers out of 3 boxes

Tags: java, algorithm

I have 3 boxes, each box contain 10 piece of numbered paper (1 - 10) but there is a number the same in all 3 boxes eg: box1 has number 4 and box2 has number 4 and box3 also has number 4. How to find that repeated number in java with an efficient/fastest way possible?

Comment: Whoa!  When is this due?

Comment: I retagged the question for you. People who can help you will be able to find your question more easily.

Comment: Can you have a same number in 2 boxes or if a number is repeated then it'll always appear in 3 boxes?

Comment: HAHA, James chill out I already took care of this one

Comment: Pierreten, you and james1 classmates? ;)

Comment: It's due soon but it isnt my homework, it's one of my friends' and i'm interested in this problem, cos i don't know myself too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i did. I am not sure whether it will be fast enough or not but there's only thing i that came up in mind. Although, i'm not sure about the computation complexity. How can you tell which code is running in O(n) n log n ... ect. I know that O (n) has 1 loop cos it's linearly. O (n log n) is has 1 and a half loop (in explanation) O(n square) has 2 loops. Since my code is like this, how can i tell? i'm abit lost here sorry.

```
    int[] jigsaw1 = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 449, 450, 451, 452, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 460, 461, 462, 463, 464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 472, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 480, 481, 482, 483, 484, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 493, 494, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 511, 512, 513, 514, 515, 516, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 522, 523, 524, 525, 526, 527, 528, 529, 530, 531, 532, 533, 534, 535, 536, 537, 538, 539, 540, 541, 542, 543, 544, 545, 546, 547, 548, 549, 550, 551, 552, 553, 554, 555, 556, 557, 558, 559, 560, 561, 562, 563, 564, 565, 566, 567, 568, 569, 570, 571, 572, 573, 574, 575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 588, 589, 590, 591, 592, 593, 594, 595, 596, 597, 598, 599, 600, 601, 602, 603, 604, 605, 606, 607, 608, 609, 610, 611, 612, 613, 614, 615, 616, 617, 618, 619, 620, 621, 622, 623, 624, 625, 626, 627, 628, 629, 630, 631, 632, 633, 634, 635, 636, 637, 638, 639, 640, 641, 642, 643, 644, 645, 646, 647, 648, 649, 650, 651, 652, 653, 654, 655, 656, 657, 658, 659, 660, 661, 662, 663, 664, 665, 666, 667, 668, 669, 670, 671, 672, 673, 674, 675, 676, 677, 678, 679, 680, 681, 682, 683, 684, 685, 686, 687, 688, 689, 690, 691, 692, 693, 694, 695, 696, 697, 698, 699, 700, 701, 702, 703, 704, 705, 706, 707, 708, 709, 710, 711, 712, 713, 714, 715, 716, 717, 718, 719, 720, 721, 722, 723, 724, 725, 726, 727, 728, 729, 730, 731, 732, 733, 734, 735, 736, 737, 738, 739, 740, 741, 742, 743, 744, 745, 746, 747, 748, 749, 750, 751, 752, 753, 754, 755, 756, 757, 758, 759, 760, 761, 762, 763, 764, 765, 766, 767, 768, 769, 770, 771, 772, 773, 774, 775, 776, 777, 778, 779, 780, 781, 782, 783, 784, 785, 786, 787, 788, 789, 790, 791, 792, 793, 794, 795, 796, 797, 798, 799, 800, 801, 802, 803, 804, 805, 806, 807, 808, 809, 810, 811, 812, 813, 814, 815, 816, 817, 818, 819, 820, 821, 822, 823, 824, 825, 826, 827, 828, 829, 830, 831, 832, 833, 834, 835, 836, 837, 838, 839, 840, 841, 842, 843, 844, 845, 846, 847, 848, 849, 850, 851, 852, 853, 854, 855, 856, 857, 858, 859, 860, 861, 862, 863, 864, 865, 866, 867, 868, 869, 870, 871, 872, 873, 874, 875, 876, 877, 878, 879, 880, 881, 882, 883, 884, 885, 886, 887, 888, 889, 890, 891, 892, 893, 894, 895, 896, 897, 898, 899, 900, 901, 902, 903, 904, 905, 906, 907, 908, 909, 910, 911, 912, 913, 914, 915, 916, 917, 918, 919, 920, 921, 922, 923, 924, 925, 926, 927, 928, 929, 930, 931, 932, 933, 934, 935, 936, 937, 938, 939, 940, 941, 942, 943, 944, 945, 946, 947, 948, 949, 950, 951, 952, 953, 954, 955, 956, 957, 958, 959, 960, 961, 962, 963, 964, 965, 966, 967, 968, 969, 970, 971, 972, 973, 974, 975, 976, 977, 978, 979, 980, 981, 982, 983, 984, 985, 986, 987, 988, 989, 990, 991, 992, 993, 994, 995, 996, 997, 998, 999, 1000};
    int[] jigsaw2 = new int[] {1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 1010, 1011, 1012, 1013, 1014, 1015, 1016, 1017, 1018, 1019, 1020, 1021, 1022, 1023, 1024, 1025, 1026, 1027, 1028, 1029, 1030, 1031, 1032, 1033, 1034, 1035, 1036, 1037, 1038, 1039, 1040, 1041, 1042, 1043, 1044, 1045, 1046, 1047, 1048, 1049, 1050, 1051, 1052, 1053, 1054, 1055, 1056, 1057, 1058, 1059, 1060, 1061, 1062, 1063, 1064, 1065, 1066, 1067, 1068, 1069, 1070, 1071, 1072, 1073, 1074, 1075, 1076, 1077, 1078, 1079, 1080, 1081, 1082, 1083, 1084, 1085, 1086, 1087, 1088, 1089, 1090, 1091, 1092, 1093, 1094, 1095, 1096, 1097, 1098, 1099, 1100, 1101, 1102, 1103, 1104, 1105, 1106, 1107, 1108, 1109, 1110, 1111, 1112, 1113, 1114, 1115, 1116, 1117, 1118, 1119, 1120, 1121, 1122, 1123, 1124, 1125, 1126, 1127, 1128, 1129, 1130, 1131, 180, 1133, 1134, 1135, 1136, 1137, 1138, 1139, 1140, 1141, 1142, 1143, 1144, 1145, 1146, 1147, 1148, 1149, 1150, 1151, 1152, 1153, 1154, 1155, 1156, 1157, 1158, 1159, 1160, 1161, 1162, 1163, 1164, 1165, 1166, 1167, 1168, 1169, 1170, 1171, 1172, 1173, 1174, 1175, 1176, 1177, 1178, 1179, 1180, 1181, 1182, 1183, 1184, 1185, 1186, 1187, 1188, 1189, 1190, 1191, 1192, 1193, 1194, 1195, 1196, 1197, 1198, 1199, 1200, 1201, 1202, 1203, 1204, 1205, 1206, 1207, 1208, 1209, 1210, 1211, 1212, 1213, 1214, 1215, 1216, 1217, 1218, 1219, 1220, 1221, 1222, 1223, 1224, 1225, 1226, 1227, 1228, 1229, 1230, 1231, 1232, 1233, 1234, 1235, 1236, 1237, 1238, 1239, 1240, 1241, 1242, 1243, 1244, 1245, 1246, 1247, 1248, 1249, 1250, 1251, 1252, 1253, 1254, 1255, 1256, 1257, 1258, 1259, 1260, 1261, 1262, 1263, 1264, 1265, 1266, 1267, 1268, 1269, 1270, 1271, 1272, 1273, 1274, 1275, 1276, 1277, 1278, 1279, 1280, 1281, 1282, 1283, 1284, 1285, 1286, 1287, 1288, 1289, 1290, 1291, 1292, 1293, 1294, 1295, 1296, 1297, 1298, 1299, 1300, 1301, 1302, 1303, 1304, 1305, 1306, 1307, 1308, 1309, 1310, 1311, 1312, 1313, 1314, 1315, 1316, 1317, 1318, 1319, 1320, 1321, 1322, 1323, 1324, 1325, 1326, 1327, 1328, 1329, 1330, 1331, 1332, 1333, 1334, 1335, 1336, 1337, 1338, 1339, 1340, 1341, 1342, 1343, 1344, 1345, 1346, 1347, 1348, 1349, 1350, 1351, 1352, 1353, 1354, 1355, 1356, 1357, 1358, 1359, 1360, 1361, 1362, 1363, 1364, 1365, 1366, 1367, 1368, 1369, 1370, 1371, 1372, 1373, 1374, 1375, 1376, 1377, 1378, 1379, 1380, 1381, 1382, 1383, 1384, 1385, 1386, 1387, 1388, 1389, 1390, 1391, 1392, 1393, 1394, 1395, 1396, 1397, 1398, 1399, 1400, 1401, 1402, 1403, 1404, 1405, 1406, 1407, 1408, 1409, 1410, 1411, 1412, 1413, 1414, 1415, 1416, 1417, 1418, 1419, 1420, 1421, 1422, 1423, 1424, 1425, 1426, 1427, 1428, 1429, 1430, 1431, 1432, 1433, 1434, 1435, 1436, 1437, 1438, 1439, 1440, 1441, 1442, 1443, 1444, 1445, 1446, 1447, 1448, 1449, 1450, 1451, 1452, 1453, 1454, 1455, 1456, 1457, 1458, 1459, 1460, 1461, 1462, 1463, 1464, 1465, 1466, 1467, 1468, 1469, 1470, 1471, 1472, 1473, 1474, 1475, 1476, 1477, 1478, 1479, 1480, 1481, 1482, 1483, 1484, 1485, 1486, 1487, 1488, 1489, 1490, 1491, 1492, 1493, 1494, 1495, 1496, 1497, 1498, 1499, 1500, 1501, 1502, 1503, 1504, 1505, 1506, 1507, 1508, 1509, 1510, 1511, 1512, 1513, 1514, 1515, 1516, 1517, 1518, 1519, 1520, 1521, 1522, 1523, 1524, 1525, 1526, 1527, 1528, 1529, 1530, 1531, 1532, 1533, 1534, 1535, 1536, 1537, 1538, 1539, 1540, 1541, 1542, 1543, 1544, 1545, 1546, 1547, 1548, 1549, 1550, 1551, 1552, 1553, 1554, 1555, 1556, 1557, 1558, 1559, 1560, 1561, 1562, 1563, 1564, 1565, 1566, 1567, 1568, 1569, 1570, 1571, 1572, 1573, 1574, 1575, 1576, 1577, 1578, 1579, 1580, 1581, 1582, 1583, 1584, 1585, 1586, 1587, 1588, 1589, 1590, 1591, 1592, 1593, 1594, 1595, 1596, 1597, 1598, 1599, 1600, 1601, 1602, 1603, 1604, 1605, 1606, 1607, 1608, 1609, 1610, 1611, 1612, 1613, 1614, 1615, 1616, 1617, 1618, 1619, 1620, 1621, 1622, 1623, 1624, 1625, 1626, 1627, 1628, 1629, 1630, 1631, 1632, 1633, 1634, 1635, 1636, 1637, 1638, 1639, 1640, 1641, 1642, 1643, 1644, 1645, 1646, 1647, 1648, 1649, 1650, 1651, 1652, 1653, 1654, 1655, 1656, 1657, 1658, 1659, 1660, 1661, 1662, 1663, 1664, 1665, 1666, 1667, 1668, 1669, 1670, 1671, 1672, 1673, 1674, 1675, 1676, 1677, 1678, 1679, 1680, 1681, 1682, 1683, 1684, 1685, 1686, 1687, 1688, 1689, 1690, 1691, 1692, 1693, 1694, 1695, 1696, 1697, 1698, 1699, 1700, 1701, 1702, 1703, 1704, 1705, 1706, 1707, 1708, 1709, 1710, 1711, 1712, 1713, 1714, 1715, 1716, 1717, 1718, 1719, 1720, 1721, 1722, 1723, 1724, 1725, 1726, 1727, 1728, 1729, 1730, 1731, 1732, 1733, 1734, 1735, 1736, 1737, 1738, 1739, 1740, 1741, 1742, 1743, 1744, 1745, 1746, 1747, 1748, 1749, 1750, 1751, 1752, 1753, 1754, 1755, 1756, 1757, 1758, 1759, 1760, 1761, 1762, 1763, 1764, 1765, 1766, 1767, 1768, 1769, 1770, 1771, 1772, 1773, 1774, 1775, 1776, 1777, 1778, 1779, 1780, 1781, 1782, 1783, 1784, 1785, 1786, 1787, 1788, 1789, 1790, 1791, 1792, 1793, 1794, 1795, 1796, 1797, 1798, 1799, 1800, 1801, 1802, 1803, 1804, 1805, 1806, 1807, 1808, 1809, 1810, 1811, 1812, 1813, 1814, 1815, 1816, 1817, 1818, 1819, 1820, 1821, 1822, 1823, 1824, 1825, 1826, 1827, 1828, 1829, 1830, 1831, 1832, 1833, 1834, 1835, 1836, 1837, 1838, 1839, 1840, 1841, 1842, 1843, 1844, 1845, 1846, 1847, 1848, 1849, 1850, 1851, 1852, 1853, 1854, 1855, 1856, 1857, 1858, 1859, 1860, 1861, 1862, 1863, 1864, 1865, 1866, 1867, 1868, 1869, 1870, 1871, 1872, 1873, 1874, 1875, 1876, 1877, 1878, 1879, 1880, 1881, 1882, 1883, 1884, 1885, 1886, 1887, 1888, 1889, 1890, 1891, 1892, 1893, 1894, 1895, 1896, 1897, 1898, 1899, 1900, 1901, 1902, 1903, 1904, 1905, 1906, 1907, 1908, 1909, 1910, 1911, 1912, 1913, 1914, 1915, 1916, 1917, 1918, 1919, 1920, 1921, 1922, 1923, 1924, 1925, 1926, 1927, 1928, 1929, 1930, 1931, 1932, 1933, 1934, 1935, 1936, 1937, 1938, 1939, 1940, 1941, 1942, 1943, 1944, 1945, 1946, 1947, 1948, 1949, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000};
    int[] jigsaw3 = new int[] {2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026, 2027, 2028, 2029, 2030, 2031, 2032, 2033, 2034, 2035, 2036, 2037, 2038, 2039, 2040, 2041, 2042, 2043, 2044, 2045, 2046, 2047, 2048, 2049, 2050, 2051, 2052, 2053, 2054, 2055, 2056, 2057, 2058, 2059, 2060, 2061, 2062, 2063, 2064, 2065, 2066, 2067, 2068, 2069, 2070, 2071, 2072, 2073, 2074, 2075, 2076, 2077, 2078, 2079, 2080, 2081, 2082, 2083, 2084, 2085, 2086, 2087, 2088, 2089, 2090, 2091, 2092, 2093, 2094, 2095, 2096, 2097, 2098, 2099, 2100, 2101, 2102, 2103, 2104, 2105, 2106, 2107, 2108, 2109, 2110, 2111, 2112, 2113, 2114, 2115, 2116, 2117, 2118, 2119, 2120, 2121, 2122, 2123, 2124, 2125, 2126, 2127, 2128, 2129, 180, 2131, 2132, 2133, 2134, 2135, 2136, 2137, 2138, 2139, 2140, 2141, 2142, 2143, 2144, 2145, 2146, 2147, 2148, 2149, 2150, 2151, 2152, 2153, 2154, 2155, 2156, 2157, 2158, 2159, 2160, 2161, 2162, 2163, 2164, 2165, 2166, 2167, 2168, 2169, 2170, 2171, 2172, 2173, 2174, 2175, 2176, 2177, 2178, 2179, 2180, 2181, 2182, 2183, 2184, 2185, 2186, 2187, 2188, 2189, 2190, 2191, 2192, 2193, 2194, 2195, 2196, 2197, 2198, 2199, 2200, 2201, 2202, 2203, 2204, 2205, 2206, 2207, 2208, 2209, 2210, 2211, 2212, 2213, 2214, 2215, 2216, 2217, 2218, 2219, 2220, 2221, 2222, 2223, 2224, 2225, 2226, 2227, 2228, 2229, 2230, 2231, 2232, 2233, 2234, 2235, 2236, 2237, 2238, 2239, 2240, 2241, 2242, 2243, 2244, 2245, 2246, 2247, 2248, 2249, 2250, 2251, 2252, 2253, 2254, 2255, 2256, 2257, 2258, 2259, 2260, 2261, 2262, 2263, 2264, 2265, 2266, 2267, 2268, 2269, 2270, 2271, 2272, 2273, 2274, 2275, 2276, 2277, 2278, 2279, 2280, 2281, 2282, 2283, 2284, 2285, 2286, 2287, 2288, 2289, 2290, 2291, 2292, 2293, 2294, 2295, 2296, 2297, 2298, 2299, 2300, 2301, 2302, 2303, 2304, 2305, 2306, 2307, 2308, 2309, 2310, 2311, 2312, 2313, 2314, 2315, 2316, 2317, 2318, 2319, 2320, 2321, 2322, 2323, 2324, 2325, 2326, 2327, 2328, 2329, 2330, 2331, 2332, 2333, 2334, 2335, 2336, 2337, 2338, 2339, 2340, 2341, 2342, 2343, 2344, 2345, 2346, 2347, 2348, 2349, 2350, 2351, 2352, 2353, 2354, 2355, 2356, 2357, 2358, 2359, 2360, 2361, 2362, 2363, 2364, 2365, 2366, 2367, 2368, 2369, 2370, 2371, 2372, 2373, 2374, 2375, 2376, 2377, 2378, 2379, 2380, 2381, 2382, 2383, 2384, 2385, 2386, 2387, 2388, 2389, 2390, 2391, 2392, 2393, 2394, 2395, 2396, 2397, 2398, 2399, 2400, 2401, 2402, 2403, 2404, 2405, 2406, 2407, 2408, 2409, 2410, 2411, 2412, 2413, 2414, 2415, 2416, 2417, 2418, 2419, 2420, 2421, 2422, 2423, 2424, 2425, 2426, 2427, 2428, 2429, 2430, 2431, 2432, 2433, 2434, 2435, 2436, 2437, 2438, 2439, 2440, 2441, 2442, 2443, 2444, 2445, 2446, 2447, 2448, 2449, 2450, 2451, 2452, 2453, 2454, 2455, 2456, 2457, 2458, 2459, 2460, 2461, 2462, 2463, 2464, 2465, 2466, 2467, 2468, 2469, 2470, 2471, 2472, 2473, 2474, 2475, 2476, 2477, 2478, 2479, 2480, 2481, 2482, 2483, 2484, 2485, 2486, 2487, 2488, 2489, 2490, 2491, 2492, 2493, 2494, 2495, 2496, 2497, 2498, 2499, 2500, 2501, 2502, 2503, 2504, 2505, 2506, 2507, 2508, 2509, 2510, 2511, 2512, 2513, 2514, 2515, 2516, 2517, 2518, 2519, 2520, 2521, 2522, 2523, 2524, 2525, 2526, 2527, 2528, 2529, 2530, 2531, 2532, 2533, 2534, 2535, 2536, 2537, 2538, 2539, 2540, 2541, 2542, 2543, 2544, 2545, 2546, 2547, 2548, 2549, 2550, 2551, 2552, 2553, 2554, 2555, 2556, 2557, 2558, 2559, 2560, 2561, 2562, 2563, 2564, 2565, 2566, 2567, 2568, 2569, 2570, 2571, 2572, 2573, 2574, 2575, 2576, 2577, 2578, 2579, 2580, 2581, 2582, 2583, 2584, 2585, 2586, 2587, 2588, 2589, 2590, 2591, 2592, 2593, 2594, 2595, 2596, 2597, 2598, 2599, 2600, 2601, 2602, 2603, 2604, 2605, 2606, 2607, 2608, 2609, 2610, 2611, 2612, 2613, 2614, 2615, 2616, 2617, 2618, 2619, 2620, 2621, 2622, 2623, 2624, 2625, 2626, 2627, 2628, 2629, 2630, 2631, 2632, 2633, 2634, 2635, 2636, 2637, 2638, 2639, 2640, 2641, 2642, 2643, 2644, 2645, 2646, 2647, 2648, 2649, 2650, 2651, 2652, 2653, 2654, 2655, 2656, 2657, 2658, 2659, 2660, 2661, 2662, 2663, 2664, 2665, 2666, 2667, 2668, 2669, 2670, 2671, 2672, 2673, 2674, 2675, 2676, 2677, 2678, 2679, 2680, 2681, 2682, 2683, 2684, 2685, 2686, 2687, 2688, 2689, 2690, 2691, 2692, 2693, 2694, 2695, 2696, 2697, 2698, 2699, 2700, 2701, 2702, 2703, 2704, 2705, 2706, 2707, 2708, 2709, 2710, 2711, 2712, 2713, 2714, 2715, 2716, 2717, 2718, 2719, 2720, 2721, 2722, 2723, 2724, 2725, 2726, 2727, 2728, 2729, 2730, 2731, 2732, 2733, 2734, 2735, 2736, 2737, 2738, 2739, 2740, 2741, 2742, 2743, 2744, 2745, 2746, 2747, 2748, 2749, 2750, 2751, 2752, 2753, 2754, 2755, 2756, 2757, 2758, 2759, 2760, 2761, 2762, 2763, 2764, 2765, 2766, 2767, 2768, 2769, 2770, 2771, 2772, 2773, 2774, 2775, 2776, 2777, 2778, 2779, 2780, 2781, 2782, 2783, 2784, 2785, 2786, 2787, 2788, 2789, 2790, 2791, 2792, 2793, 2794, 2795, 2796, 2797, 2798, 2799, 2800, 2801, 2802, 2803, 2804, 2805, 2806, 2807, 2808, 2809, 2810, 2811, 2812, 2813, 2814, 2815, 2816, 2817, 2818, 2819, 2820, 2821, 2822, 2823, 2824, 2825, 2826, 2827, 2828, 2829, 2830, 2831, 2832, 2833, 2834, 2835, 2836, 2837, 2838, 2839, 2840, 2841, 2842, 2843, 2844, 2845, 2846, 2847, 2848, 2849, 2850, 2851, 2852, 2853, 2854, 2855, 2856, 2857, 2858, 2859, 2860, 2861, 2862, 2863, 2864, 2865, 2866, 2867, 2868, 2869, 2870, 2871, 2872, 2873, 2874, 2875, 2876, 2877, 2878, 2879, 2880, 2881, 2882, 2883, 2884, 2885, 2886, 2887, 2888, 2889, 2890, 2891, 2892, 2893, 2894, 2895, 2896, 2897, 2898, 2899, 2900, 2901, 2902, 2903, 2904, 2905, 2906, 2907, 2908, 2909, 2910, 2911, 2912, 2913, 2914, 2915, 2916, 2917, 2918, 2919, 2920, 2921, 2922, 2923, 2924, 2925, 2926, 2927, 2928, 2929, 2930, 2931, 2932, 2933, 2934, 2935, 2936, 2937, 2938, 2939, 2940, 2941, 2942, 2943, 2944, 2945, 2946, 2947, 2948, 2949, 2950, 2951, 2952, 2953, 2954, 2955, 2956, 2957, 2958, 2959, 2960, 2961, 2962, 2963, 2964, 2965, 2966, 2967, 2968, 2969, 2970, 2971, 2972, 2973, 2974, 2975, 2976, 2977, 2978, 2979, 2980, 2981, 2982, 2983, 2984, 2985, 2986, 2987, 2988, 2989, 2990, 2991, 2992, 2993, 2994, 2995, 2996, 2997, 2998, 2999, 3000};

    ArrayList<Integer> boxes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    quick_srt(jigsaw2,0,jigsaw2.length-1);
    quick_srt(jigsaw3,0,jigsaw3.length-1);

    int median,median1;
    int index,index1;
    //Check for median of Jigsaw2 and Jigsaw3
    if(jigsaw2.length % 2==0){
        median=(jigsaw2[jigsaw2.length/2]+jigsaw2[jigsaw2.length/2+1])/2;
        index=(jigsaw2.length/2+jigsaw2.length/2+1)/2;
    }
    else{
        median = jigsaw2[jigsaw2.length/2];
        index=jigsaw2.length/2;
    }
    if(jigsaw3.length % 2==0){
        median1=(jigsaw3[jigsaw3.length/2]+jigsaw3[jigsaw3.length/2+1])/2;
        index1=(jigsaw3.length/2+jigsaw3.length/2+1)/2;
    }
    else
        median1 = jigsaw3[jigsaw3.length/2];
        index1 = jigsaw3.length/2;
        //Check to see if Jigsaw1 equal to Jigsaw2 and Jigsaw3
        for(int h=0;h<jigsaw1.length;h++){
            //Check with the Median of Jigsaw 2
            if(jigsaw1[h]<median){
                for(int j=index-1;j>=0;j--){
                    if(jigsaw1[h]==jigsaw2[j]){
                        //Check with the Median of Jigsaw 3
                        if(jigsaw1[h]<median1){
                            for(int sec=index1;sec>=0;sec--){
                                if(jigsaw1[h]==jigsaw3[sec]){
                                    boxes.add(jigsaw1[h]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if(jigsaw1[h]>median1){
                            for(int sec1=index1;sec1<jigsaw3.length;sec1++){
                                if(jigsaw1[h]==jigsaw3[sec1]){
                                    boxes.add(jigsaw1[h]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if(jigsaw1[h]==median1){
                            boxes.add(jigsaw1[h]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(jigsaw1[h]==median){
                if(jigsaw1[h]<median1){
                    for(int sec2=index1;sec2>=0;sec2--){
                        if(jigsaw1[h]==jigsaw3[sec2]){
                            boxes.add(jigsaw1[h]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(jigsaw1[h]>median1){
                    for(int sec3=index1;sec3<jigsaw3.length;sec3++){
                        if(jigsaw1[h]==jigsaw3[sec3]){
                            boxes.add(jigsaw1[h]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(jigsaw1[h]==median1){
                    boxes.add(jigsaw1[h]);
                }
            }
            else{
                /*for(int k=index;k<=jigsaw1.length-1;k++){
                    if(jigsaw1[h]==jigsaw1[k]){
                        //list.add(Jigsaw2[h]);
                    }
                }*/
                if(jigsaw1[h]<median1){
                    for(int sec4=index1;sec4>=0;sec4--){
                        if(jigsaw1[h]==jigsaw3[sec4]){
                            boxes.add(jigsaw1[h]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(jigsaw1[h]>median1){
                    for(int sec5=index1;sec5<jigsaw3.length;sec5++){
                        if(jigsaw1[h]==jigsaw3[sec5]){
                            boxes.add(jigsaw1[h]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(jigsaw1[h]==median1){
                    boxes.add(jigsaw1[h]);
                }
            }
        }
        return boxes;
    }

public static void quick_srt(int Jigsaw1[],int low, int height){
    int lo = low;
    int hi = height;
    if (lo >= height) {
      return;
    }
    int mid = Jigsaw1[(lo + hi) / 2];
    while (lo < hi) {
      while (lo<hi && Jigsaw1[lo] < mid) {
        lo++;
      }
      while (lo<hi && Jigsaw1[hi] > mid) {
        hi--;
      }
      if (lo < hi) {
        int T = Jigsaw1[lo];
        Jigsaw1[lo] = Jigsaw1[hi];
        Jigsaw1[hi] = T;
      }
    }
    if (hi < lo) {
      int T = hi;
      hi = lo;
      lo = T;
    }
    quick_srt(Jigsaw1, low, lo);
    quick_srt(Jigsaw1, lo == low ? lo+1 : lo, height);
```

I used quicksort to sort the second and third and then loop through check with the unsorted of first array.
Anyway that could make it even faster and probably abit more simplify the logic?
Thanks

Comment: You can use data structures to help. a `TreeSet` (a Red/Black tree, basically) can build in `O(N log N)`, and find elements in `O(log N)`, and you wouldn't have to write all these stuff yourself. a `HashSet` has expected `O(1)` find operation. This would enable a linear-time solution.

Comment: That looks a little... overcomplicated.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: i'm sorry, i don't really get it. Could u please give a psuedocode? The above solution is all i could think of. I know, i'm very basic on programming.

Comment: @james1: I can explain WizardOfOdds' tricky solution, but I don't think that's the most helpful way for you now. I can give pseudocode, but it would only hide the complexity under the data structure routines. My best recommendation is for you to pick up an elementary algorithm and data structure book, and learn about binary search, binary search tree, and hashtables. You don't have to know every little details, but at least you should get the general idea of what functionalities they offer, and at what cost.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: Thanks, i will do so.

Answer (score 4):

I'd start with something simple that works, and get more clever (more efficient and faster) later.

- What's the simplest way that would work?  (Hint: step through all 30 slips of paper and find the winner brute force.)
- Do the same thing but have an exit condition.  When can you stop looking?  How much do those checks cost you?

Comment: +1 agrees with Michael -- good way to respond to a homework question

Answer (score 1):

Reading your problem description *"each box contain 10 piece of numbered paper (1 - 10) but there is a number the same in all 3 boxes"* I take it that:

- each box has **exactly** ten pieces of paper
- each piece of paper has a number from 1 to 10 on it
- there is **only** one number that appears in all three boxes
- (hence, other numbers may appear more than once)

Like here, where the number '8' is the only one to appear in all three boxes.

```
    int[] a = new int[] {  3,  2,  7,  5,  8,  2, 10,  6,  9,  7,  3 };
    int[] b = new int[] {  1,  4,  8,  7,  5,  1,  3,  2,  2,  4,  1 };
    int[] c = new int[] {  8,  4,  1,  6, 10,  9,  6,  4,  9,  6,  4 };
```

Is that your problem?

Then you wrote: *"How to find that repeated number in java with an efficient/fastest way possible?"*

Now *how* efficient/fast do you want to be? Are you talking about O(n) efficient (even though the boxes are unsorted), like here (slightly obfuscated to confuse you a bit):

```
    int s = 0;
    int t = 0;
    int u = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        s |= 1 << a[i];
        t |= 1 << b[i];
        u |= 1 << c[i];
    }
    System.out.println( Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros( s & t & u ) );
```

; )

Somehow I'm not sure your teacher will think you came up with that answer : )

Comment: @polygenelubricants: eh eh thanks and if you didn't know about it then you *must* go take a look at its implementation.  A pure jewel of low-level bit hackery :)  It is definitely worth a look :)

Comment: I used probably the same bit twiddling technique before (specifically in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627225/al-zimmermanns-son-of-darts); I just didn't expect `Integer` to provide something like this for me.

Comment: I had no idea too. I'm just trying to help 1 of my friends. He gave this problem and unfortunately, i couldn't help him cos i've known only the simple and slow way which is loop in loop. Although, the problem is looking to be solved as efficient as possible, that's what it says.

Comment: By the way, the above code works find but yeah that would give the teacher a big puzzle.
Could you please explain in java? so i could understand it more and as well as my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple algorithm to solve it. It's not the fastest/most efficient, but since you're struggling with even the simplest logic, this one should be educational. It's presented here in pseudocode with comments:

```
Boolean boxHasNumber(Box b, Number x) // does Box b have Number x?
  FOR EVERY Number n IN Box b
     IF n = x RETURN True
  // otherwise x is not in box
  RETURN False

Number sameNumber(Box b1, b2, b3) // which number appears in all 3 boxes?
  FOR EVERY Number x FROM 1 TO 10
     IF boxHasNumber(b1, x) AND
        boxHasNumber(b2, x) AND
        boxHasNumber(b3, x)
             RETURN x
  // otherwise, no number appears in all 3 boxes
  ERROR
```

Note the use of what is called *helper function*. Basically, the logic of finding if a number is in a box is encapsulated in its own complete, reusable, testable, function. This makes the overall logic more readable.

Comment: To downvoters: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812  "You can use pseudo-code" / "Don't downvote others who answer homework questions in good faith"

Comment: @polygenelubricants: ++ from me too.  I've gotten smacked down before for answering HW questions, so that's why I just give hints now.  But you're not giving working code, so I deem your answer to be a hint. ;)

Comment: @polygenelubricants: Thanks for the help but i know how to do it in the simplest way like you have stated above. I just don't know the efficient and fastest way in algorithms to do it.

Comment: @james1: next time write what you've done. It shows that you've put effort, and it gives us an idea how to best help you. For absolute speed, WizardOfOdds' solution is unbeatable given the constraints.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: Yes i should. I'm new to this stackoverflow that's why, sorry. Anyway, yes i've tried that WizardOfOdds code, but it isnt in java, i think it's in Haskell or something. I don't understand that code at all. if you do, could you please explain? thanks

Comment: @james1: I'll give WizardOfOdds some time to explain his solution, but if he doesn't give one in the next few days, remind me with another comment and I'll do it. Meanwhile, you can read on wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation specifically OR, AND and SHIFT.

Comment: @polygenelubricants:Yes i've tried his solution by changing the array and apparently it didnt work. Had no idea.

Comment: @james1: Maybe you can edit your question and provide the testcase that fails, because that solution should work if his assumed constraints are true (10 numbers, numbers between 1-10, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose each box is a [`List<Integer>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of the numbers in it. The [`contains()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method would let you know if a box has that number. You can even write your own `contains()` method by going through the list one element at a time to find a match. Here's a [guide](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) to looping through a collection such as a [`List<Integer>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Answer (score 0):

One way might be:

- Simulate the boxes by arrays of 10 elements. Initialize it.
- Element `i` is present in `box_j` if `box_j[i-1] == 1`
- Iterate over the numbers 0-9 and check if `box_j[num-1] == 1 for each j`

Code this in java for yourself :P.

**EDIT:** 
I an taking your question as described by WizzardOfOdds in his answer.

What I was telling was:
take three arrays `box1[],box2[],box3[]`

Let the input for first box be `1,5,5,5,6,7,6,6,6,8` written on the 10 paper sheets, then

- Initialize it as `box1[i-1] = 1` for every i in `1,5,5,5,6,7,6,6,6,8`
- repeat for other two boxes similarly
- Now do this: `check if box1[i]==1 && box2[i]==1 && box3[i]==1` for i in 0-9
- The repeated number will be `i+1` for that value of `i` for which above is true

Comment: Sorry dont really understand this, maybe abit more details please?