# how to find the minimum number which can't be represented by an input sequence

Tags: algorithm

Here is an interview question:
Input:
Integer N; different positive integers a1, a2 ... aN;

Output:
the minimum positive integer m, which cannot be represented in the form m = x1*a1+x2*a2+...xN*aN, where xi={0,1}.

Comment: I wonder if there is any better approach than enumerating all 2^n possibilities.  Seems related to the knapsack problem, although I do not see an actual reduction.

Comment: It's also related to polynomial universal codes.

Answer (score 1):

naive solution:

```
public static void calcAllSums(int[] arr, int sum, int curIndex, Hashtable<Integer,Boolean> sums){
    if (curIndex == arr.length) return;
    int sum1 = sum+arr[curIndex];
    int sum2 = sum;
    sums.put(sum1, true);
    sums.put(sum2, true);
    calcAllSums(arr, sum1, curIndex+1, sums);
    calcAllSums(arr, sum2, curIndex+1, sums);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] arr = {1,3,5};
    Hashtable<Integer,Boolean> sums = new Hashtable<Integer,Boolean>();
    calcAllSums(arr, 0, 0, sums);
    int i=0;
    while (sums.containsKey(i)) i++;
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

i calculated all possible sums, and iterated until i found an integer which is not in the list

Comment: given problem is a variant of subset sum problem which is NP hard problem and best solution is O(2^n/2). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem , above algo takes O(2^n) which is indeed optimized in summing.

Answer (score 1):

For extremely fast all-sums-of-3-numbers code,
see [explanation at polygenelubricants.com](http://www.polygenelubricants.com/2009/11/on-aliakseis-opus-2.html) of code by Aliaksei Safryhin.  The series of 
statements like

```
*pTo++ += short(*pFrom++) << 8; *pTo++ += short(*pFrom++) << 8;
```

may look clumsy and slow, but in my tests ran many times faster than shifted-bit-map methods.  Also see [Al Zimmermann's Son of Darts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627225/al-zimmermanns-son-of-darts) and [How can I improve this algorithm for solving a modified Postage Stamp puzzle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785832/how-can-i-improve-this-algorithm-for-solving-a-modified-postage-stamp-problem) and if you can find darts.pdf by John Morris, 7 July 2010, it contains code of a fairly fast enumerator for first-missing-subset-sums for 3 to 20 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Since the minimal difference between two successive numbers is the least of the a<sub>n</sub> factors, and 0 is representable, I'd say

min<sub>n</sub>(a<sub>n</sub>) - 1

Of course, if min<sub>n</sub>(a<sub>n</sub>) = 1, you could make a similar reasoning for the second-to-minimum.